# Output is not rendered on Django template for the same model whose output is rendered on another template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am really new to Django and I am building a website while learning it. As per requirements, I have to show some news articles on both the home page and on another page that I navigate from the navbar. I have shown the articles list and individual details with the loop in my template files. Problem is, although I have written the for loop for rendering the news article on the home page, nothing is showing up. Following are my models.py, views.py, app/urls.py, and project/urls.py files :

```
    #models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField



class Post(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published'),
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
# slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
slug = models.CharField(_("Slug"), max_length=200)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
body = RichTextField()
# image_header = models.ImageField(unique=True, default=timezone.now)
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
# created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
# updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:details', args=[self.slug])



class News(models.Model):
        STATUS_CHOICES = (
            ('draft', 'Draft'),
            ('published', 'Published'),
        )
        news_title = models.CharField(max_length=250) unique_for_date='nw_publish', unique=True, null=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique_for_date='nw_publish')
        news_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='news_posts')
        news_body = RichTextField()
        image_header = models.ImageField(upload_to='featured_image/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
    
        nw_publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        nw_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
        news_tags = TaggableManager()
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('nw_publish',)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.news_title
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news:news_detail', args=[self.slug])

     #views.py
    from django.views import generic
    from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
    from django.http import Http404
    from .models import Post, Report, News, Member, Project

    class Home(ListView):
        model = Post
        context_object_name = 'home'
        template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    
    
    class HomeDetail(generic.DetailView):
        model = Post
        context_object_name = 'details'
        template_name = 'blog/details.html'

   class NewsListView(ListView):
         model = News
         context_object_name = 'newss'
         template_name = 'blog/news.html'
    
    
    class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
        model = News
        context_object_name = 'news'
        template_name = 'blog/news_detail.html'
#app/urls.py

from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views
from .views import Home, HomeDetail, Contact, ReportListView, ReportDetailView, NewsListView, NewsDetailView

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    path('', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('home/<slug:slug>/', HomeDetail.as_view(), name='details'),
    path('news/', NewsListView.as_view(), name='news_list'),
    path('news/<slug:slug>/', NewsDetailView.as_view(), name='news_detail'),
    path('contact/', Contact.as_view(), name='contact'),
]


 #project/urls.py

   
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  path('', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
                  path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
                  path('members/', include('blog.urls', namespace='members')),
                  path('news/', include('blog.urls', namespace='news')),
                  path('contact/', include('blog.urls', namespace='contact')),

              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Now my template file for new list has the following block of codes and the objects are rendered :

```
<div class="row">
            {% for news in newss %}
                <div class="col-lg-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                    <!--News Two Single-->
                    <div class="news-two__single">
                        <div class="news-two__img-box">
                            <div class="news-two__img">
                                {% if news.image_header %}
                                    <img src={{ news.image_header.url }} alt="{{ news.news_title }}">
                                {% endif %}
                                <a href={{ news.get_absolute_url }}>
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news-two__date">
                                <p>{{ news.nw_publish |date:"M d, Y" }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="news-two__content">

                            <ul class="list-unstyled news-two__meta">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i> {{ news.news_author }}</a></li>

                            </ul>
                            <h3>
                                <a href={{ news.get_absolute_url }}>{{ news.news_title }}</a>
                            </h3>
                            <p class="news-two__text">{{ news.news_body | truncatechars:110 | safe }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

On my home page, I need to achieve something like the following:

[news page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hizz9.png)

I added the following code to render the object, but it's blank:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6">
                    
                    {% for news in newss %}
                        <div class="news-one__left">
                            <div class="news-one__img">

                                <img src={% static "assets/images/blog/news-one-img-1.jpg" %} alt="">
                                <a href="{{news.get_absolute_url}}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news-one__bottom">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled news-one__meta">
                                    <li>20 Jan, 2021</li>
                                    <li><span>/</span></li>
                                </ul>
                                <h3 class="news-one__title">
                                    <a href="news-details.html">{{ news.news_title }}</a>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

The output looks like this:

[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNKVl.png)

My Django version is 3.27.2 and my python version is 3.6.8.

Sorry for such a silly question. I am trying to achieve:

1. All the news articles both on the home page and news page as a list
2. Show the first news in the left box and the rest of the 3 or 4 news in the right side box

But the output of the loop is not visible as per the attached image. Please point me to what I am doing wrong here. I am stuck for a while. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your home view is rendered by path('', Home.as_view(), name='home'), this url right? and i want to know how you are passing the context data to this template from view as you havn't mentioned home view..

Comment: You are right. I updated the code by including the view codes of the home page. Note that, my home page has some other data to render hence it has a model called 'Post' .

Comment: In home List view you are using home as context and expecting to get news as context. While in news list template it will work as you have used newss as context from this listview.

Comment: Here's the issue. I'm showing post objects which are in the Post model. For storing news data, I created the News model. Now I want the data of **News** model too on my home page, and **Post** model does not have the data of News model. If I use the home context for looping the News objects, HTML is rendered but the rendered data is from Post model. How to get the data of News model while the context is 'home'? Do I need to do anything with my models?

Comment: To add an extra data to context you have to override get_context_data() method and add news data in existing context having posts data then pass it on to your template.

Comment: Thank you so much! Being a newbie in Django, I didn't know about this method and how it works. You pointed me in the right direction and I was able to solve the issues that had me stuck. Have a good day and thanks again for your time.

Comment: Great to hear that! Kudos to community :)